# Spring: setAutoGrowCollectionLimit not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, tags

i'm using the method setAutoGrowCollectionLimit  on the binder to expand lists capacity but still i get the error.
I checked on other answers and it seems that the only thing to do in order to avoid the indexOutOfbound is the autoGrowCollectionLimit to be set with a larger number.
Thats excatly what i have done.

That's the code i've implemented:

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW", params = { "state=insertEdit" })
@SessionAttributes({ BaseController.ABI, InsertEditController.OLD_USER_MODEL, InsertEditController.ASSOCIATE_SIGNERS_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE, InsertEditController.ASSOCIATE_SIGNERS_ADM_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE, InsertEditController.ENABLE_CHECK_OTP, SignAuthUtils.FLAG_AAP })
public class InsertEditController  extends BaseController{   

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(PortletRequestDataBinder binder, Locale locale) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(messageSource.getMessage("datePattern", null, locale));
        dateFormat.setLenient(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));

        DecimalFormat currencyFormat = new DecimalFormat(messageSource.getMessage("currencyPattern", null, locale), DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale));
        currencyFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, currencyFormat, true));

        binder.setValidator(validator);

        binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(5000);
    }
```

I've also set the property at the BaseController

```
public class BaseController {


@InitBinder
public void initBinder(PortletRequestDataBinder binder, Locale locale) {

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(newDateFormat(locale), true));

    binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class,
            newCurrencyFormat(locale), true));

    binder.setValidator(validator);

    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(500);
}
```

But still i get this exception:

```
2019-11-14 11:06:24,820 [http-bio-18080-exec-12]    WARN [03440-W1559404-W1559404] o.s.w.p.DispatcherPortlet:1195 - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'listEnableCompany.results[256]' of bean class [com.cedac.smallbusiness.web.usermanagement.dto.UserCompleteDTO]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'results[256]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:830)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:574)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.PortletRequestDataBinder.bind(PortletRequestDataBinder.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$PortletHandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:805)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:359)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:360)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleResource(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doResourceService(DispatcherPortlet.java:825)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.serveResource(FrameworkPortlet.java:477)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:118)
    at com.cedac.smallbusiness.web.tags.combomanager.filter.ComboManagerPortletFilter.doFilter(ComboManagerPortletFilter.java:211)
    at com.cedac.framework.core.portlets.security.filter.DelegatingPortletFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingPortletFilterProxy.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1230.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1484.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:112)
    at com.cedac.framework.core.portlets.security.ui.portlet.PortletPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(PortletPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:111)
    at com.cedac.framework.core.portlets.security.filter.DelegatingPortletFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingPortletFilterProxy.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1230.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1484.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:112)
    at com.cedac.framework.core.portlets.security.context.PortletSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(PortletSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:166)
    at com.cedac.framework.core.portlets.security.filter.DelegatingPortletFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingPortletFilterProxy.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1230.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1484.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:112)
    at com.cedac.framework.core.portlets.logging.MDCInsertingPrincipalNamePortletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingPrincipalNamePortletFilter.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1230.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1484.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:531)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:626)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.serveResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:436)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:1075)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:719)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:560)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:537)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at it.smc.icbpi.ibk.hook.servlet.filters.LoginRedirectFilter.processFilter(LoginRedirectFilter.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor711.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy595.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:241)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:246)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:216)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.cedac.webcontoc.web.message.filter.MessageFilter.doFilter(MessageFilter.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor711.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy685.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at it.smc.icbpi.ibk.hook.servlet.filters.URLRewriteFilter.processFilter(URLRewriteFilter.java:26)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor711.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy595.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at it.mj.iguard.servlets.IgFilter.doFilter(IgFilter.java:74)
    at it.icbpi.iguard.hook.filter.IGFilterWrapper.processFilter1(IGFilterWrapper.java:78)
    at it.icbpi.iguard.hook.filter.IGFilterWrapper.processFilter(IGFilterWrapper.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor711.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy586.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:790)
    ... 212 common frames omitted
```

Do you guys have any idea what's going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I moved the binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(500) as first instruction and now it works.

```
    @InitBinder
public void initBinder(PortletRequestDataBinder binder, Locale locale) {
    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(5000); //this goes at the top
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(newDateFormat(locale), true));

    binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class,
            newCurrencyFormat(locale), true));

    binder.setValidator(validator);


}
```